# How to include PostgreSQL error where clause in data passed to application?

Tags: postgresql

Currently, when there is an error, PostgreSQL only returns an error message to my application, e.g.,

```
[42601] ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
```

But, if I run the same query in a SQL tool like DataGrip I see an additional where message that tells me where the problem is actually occurring, e.g.,

```
[42601] ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns 
Where: PL/pgSQL function trigger_assort_md() line 17 at SQL statement
```

How can I get PostgreSQL to return the where message in addition to the error message? I presume I need to make a change in postgresql.conf, I just don't know what change to make.

Comment: It is highly depending on the framework you are using for the application. Look at the [`PQresultErrorField` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-exec.html) to know how to get details about error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use this : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS-VALUES +